# ASP.NET MVC Web APi application is prompting to open a json file

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Forgive my in-experience and impatience to try and figure out ASP.NET MVC stuff out. Sounds like same issue as [Json results prompting "Save As" dialog in browser instead of being processed. ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743818/json-results-prompting-save-as-dialog-in-browser-instead-of-being-processed-a) however this is using jquery as supposed to angularjs so the answer lies here I am sure of it. Anyhow, I originally had code to load my page on a get http request as follows:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(List<HistoryItem>))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get() {...}
```

I have since added a similar signature as in:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(List<HistoryItem>))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id) { ... }
```

And in my web page (Index.cshtml) I have:

```
...
<li ng-repeat="history in historyItems">
    <a href="api/crosswordhelper/{{history.id}}">{{history.SearchExpression}}</a>
</li>
...
```

I.e. I am using angularjs to load a list of hyperlinks.
The correct server side get function is being called (i.e. the one with the id parameter) as I have a break point set that is reached. However, the issue I am having is rather than loading the part of the page the purpose of the call after the get request successfully exists - in Chrome it loads just the response only i.e. the Json file which includes the details of the hyperlink being selected (i.e. id and search expression) and in I.E. it prompts you either load or save the json file neither is what I desire. So there is something wrong or missing in my code? How do I just load the page as normal.

I am not messed with the default server routing which is in the WebApiConfig class:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Use camel case for JSON data.
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

I am guessing maybe my client side is not sufficient. Maybe I need an extra $http.get call in my angular js script file which includes the parameter, currently it is

```
$http.get("api/crosswordHelper").then(..., ...);
```

and this call is inside a function so perhaps I need my hyperlink to call my function or I need to include client side routing, can someone please advise.

Comment: I am confused as to what you are trying to accomplish.  You're providing a link to a WebAPI endpoint, which is not going to return HTML - it's only going to return JSON data which you must then consume.  So, to clarify, what is the user supposed to see once they click on the hyperlink?

Comment: I guess you are on right thinking at the end. Especially IE does offer to save/download the file. So instead if you explicitly call the service get data and display it, then all would be in your control. It could be either jQuery or Angular also.

Comment: @Brendan-Green the program is like WordFinder app on a Android phone you type in an expression (which can include wildcards) and it returns a list of matching words, eg if I type in A? then it finds all 2 letter words in the dictionary starting with A. I just have one extra functionality that saves a history of all the users request and I am displaying them in a list of hyperlinks, ie it saves you having to type the same expression twice, the user can refer to its own history to avoid re-calculating. So yes I do need to get the correct response and consume it but how do I do that?